# Passing a list of arguments into a class

Tags: python, list, class, init

I am creating a class called `Triangle`. Within `Triangle`, it is passed `three_points` list and `two_angles` list (i.e. `self.triangle0 = Triangle([1, 2, 3], [20, 30])`)

I am defining

```
class Triangle(object):

    def __init__(self, three_points, two_angles):
        self.points = three_points
        self.angles = two_angles
```

Since it is a list I am passing in and not just a single number, do I have to create lists to put the values in or does this just work?

Comment: What do you mean *"just work"*? What does work *mean* in this context? **Why don't you try it?** It will certainly work if what you expect is that the `points` attribute will be a list, but is that the behaviour you want? Also, I'd suggest you use a tuple instead, as they're immutable.

Comment: Your example doesn't quite make sense -- you are passing three scalars instead of 3 *points* (which would themselves be pairs of numbers). By the way, perhaps your question is if you need to *name* the lists before passing them to the constructors. If so, the answer is "no" -- you can just pass list literals.

Answer (score 0):

This will work how you have it mocked up. At runtime self.points will be a list containing whatever values you passed in. Same with self.angels. Note that if your list contains objects and not just primitives you may be passing in a pointer in your list and not the actual object.